# Did I solve this Lagrange multiplier correctly? (Minimizing $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ with constraint $x+2y-5=0$ and $x>0$ and $y>0$.)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Okay, so we're given this equation 
$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and the constraint is 
$x+2y-5=0$, and that $x>0$ and $y>0$,we have to find the minimum.

My answer is $(1,2)$, and my work is shown below.

> Can anyone just check if I'm doing this correctly?

[image]

Comment: why dy/dx equals=-1/2,shouldn't it be dx/dy=1/2?  
also do you mean my final answer isn't correct? @ian

Comment: It's easy to check the answer...writing $x=5-2y$ you can substitute for $x$ in $f(x,y)$ to get a function of one variable, which can then be minimized directly.

Comment: My apologies, I misread your handwriting. I thought you wrote $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=\frac{\lambda}{2\lambda}$ but you wrote $\frac{2x}{2y}=\frac{\lambda}{2\lambda}$, which is correct. I've removed my other comments. (One of many reasons to learn to use MathJax!)

Comment: Small editorial points : $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ should be $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$. Same for the others derivatives.

Comment: @Ian its okay,but like my final answer is correct right? that the point would be (1,2)

Comment: The constraint is a line and the objective function is the square of the distance of the point from the origin. You can check your own work by finding the nearest point on this line to the origin some other way, such as by intersecting it with its perpendicular through the origin. Happily, this point lies in the first quadrant (otherwise the original problem wouldn’t have had a solution in the first place).

Comment: I found the same point by calculating it again. Please mind the last component, the point is $P(1, 2, 5)$.